# How to sum the total quantity if the field with 2 or more data in it

Tags: php, sql

Here are my tables:

```
InvoiceID  FoodID  Quantity
       1    1,2      1,1
       2    2,4,5    1,1,1
```

For example, I want to get the quantity of FoodID 2,

```
SELECT SUM(quantity)
FROM table
WHERE FoodID
IN ( 2 )
```

The code will show "1" to be the answer, but the answer is 2. 
How can I get the correct Quantity?

Comment: What RDMBS are you using?

Comment: thats a bad table structure.. u may think of normalizing it

Comment: why is your table created like this? If you still can you should change your table structure.